# Is $t\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^n1_{(t_{i-1},t_i]}(t)$ with $0=t_0<\ldots<t_n$ left- or right-continuos?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

Let $0=t_0<\ldots<t_n$ and $$f(t):=\sum_{i=1}^n1_{(t_{i-1},t_i]}(t)$$ I'm confused whether $f$ is left-continuous or right-continuous. How can we prove it? It seems to be easy, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left-continuous at a point means that the function is equal to the left-hand limit at a point: as $t \uparrow a$, in other words.

Presumably your problem is at the points $t_i$. Let's look at $t_0$: for $t<t_0$, $f(t)=0$. Now, because we have $1_{(t_0,t_1]}$, the value of $f(t_0)$ is still $0$. Therefore,
$$ \lim_{t \uparrow t_0} 1_{(t_0,t_1]}(t) = 0 = 1_{(t_0,t_1]}(t_0), $$
so $1_{(t_0,t_1]}$ is left-continuous at $t$. It is not right-continous because the right-hand limit,
$$ \lim_{t \downarrow t_0} 1_{(t_0,t_1]} = 1,  $$
which is not $f(t_0)$. You can do the same at $t_n$. On the other hand, at all the intermediate points, $f(t)=1$, because $(t_{i-1},t_i] \cup (t_i,t_{i+1}] = (t_{i-1},t_{i+1}]$.